# How do I create a multivariate network analysis graph in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, plotly, networkx, multivariate-testing

I've searched for this extensively, but most of the results I get are research papers, not tutorials.

The closest thing I've found is assigning multiple attributes to edges or nodes in directed graphs, but I'm not sure if this is the same thing as a multivariate network graph (which takes into account multiple variables interacting with each other between a pair of nodes).

For example, how do I visualize the relationship between pairs of business partners while taking into account the value of their deals, their geographies, their intentions with their deals, etc?

Can someone here please provide a resource on how to create a multivariate network analysis graph in python 3? Thanks so much.

Comment: if you link to at least one of the resources that you have trouble with that might help to get a response here, or perhaps clarify by giving a more specific example of desired output.  Networkx has a `MultiGraph` class of graph representation, which allows for multiple edges between the same nodes. But having multiple attributes to the same edge is easy to do.